# Post is blank when I click on the link

Tags: posts, permalinks, urls

As I'm adding posts to a new website, the link is showing up on the page as I wanted them to.

```
http://fohh.vavee.com/anniversary-celebration
```

The problem is that when I click on the link I end up with a blank frame with no content.

```
http://fohh.vavee.com/'/2017/06/24/harmony-hall-launches-10th-anniversary-celebration/'
```

Is this as simple as a function that I haven't enabled or something more serious?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Get to your site's Settings > Permalinks please and [edit] your question and inform us what setting's there.

Comment: Hi. What are those `'` in your URL? They seem weird.

Answer (score 1):

Your site puts quotes in the permalink structure. Find out where these things come from. Without these quotes it appears to work.

http://fohh.vavee.com/2017/06/24/harmony-hall-launches-10th-anniversary-celebration/

A temporary VERY dirty solution is to filter the quotes out of the global $content variable.